# Django's form textarea doesn't appear in template

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm a beginner in Django and I'm trying to create a form. The problem is that when I am rendering the form, the `Textarea` field doesn't appear, but the button does.

The project is a twitter-like app, the form is where the user puts the text to and then posts it.

## forms.py:

```
from Django import forms


class TweetForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 1, 'cols': 85}), max_length=160)
    Country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

## views.py:

```
class PostTweet(View):
    """Tweet Post form available on page /user/<username> URL"""
    def post(self, request, username):
        form = TweetForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            tweet = Tweet(text=form.cleaned_data['text'],
                      user=user,
                      country=form.cleaned_data['country'])
            tweet.save()
            words = form.cleaned_data['text'].split(" ")
            for word in words:
                if word[0] == "#":
                    hashtag, created = HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name=word[1:])
                    hashtag.tweet.add(tweet)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/'+username)
```

## template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
      <form method="post" action="post/">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 fieldWrapper">
          {{ form.text.errors }}
          {{ form.text }}
        </div>
        {{ form.Country.as_hidden }}
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="post">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
      {% for tweet in tweets %}
        <div class="well">
          <span>{{tweet.text}}</span>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

## Output:

[image: Django textarea field problem]

Comment: pls improve your snippets to pep8

Comment: So where's the `get` method that displays the form?

Comment: @DanielRoseman where I should add the `get` method?

Comment: @Saeed Provide how you create form and pass it to template context on GET method or when your form is invalid.

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk These are all my code has for displaying the form :/

Comment: Then you **haven't** got any code for displaying the form, so it's a mystery how you think it will be displayed.

Comment: Saeed how are you displaying the form ? show your get request code ?

Comment: @shuboy2014 I'm displaying it with the template as I'd mentioned. Where I should add get method?

Comment: @DanielRoseman as I mentioned, I'm a beginner and I'm trying a book's guides step by step. The book's doesn't have any get method in this section.

Comment: Then you need to find some better instructions. I recommend the official tutorial.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Roseman mentioned, you need to define a GET method that shows the form. Just add it to your `PostTweet` class:

```
def get(self, request):
    form = TweetForm()
    return render(request, 'template/path/here.html', {'form': form})
```

Django Girls has a [nice tutorial on forms](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/). Although their views aren't class-based like yours, it's basically the same thing.

Comment: I added what you said and still doesn't work. It doesn't display the text field in current url (same as screenshot - http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/user1/). After clicking on "Post" button, it goes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/user1/post and displays the text field there.

Comment: "After clicking on "Post" button, it goes to 127.0.0.1:8000/user/user1/post and displays the text field there."

I don't understand what you mean. Can you upload a screenshot? Keep in mind that I cannot access URLs like 127.0.0.1:8000; those are local to your computer.